# Why MAUI app startup time on iOS is so slow?

Tags: ios, .net, startup, maui, .net-maui

I am facing a problem that MAUI app startup on iOS is much slower than on Android or Windows.

The deployment is done using Visual Studio Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1 and I have tried to create and deploy a new project, without any additions.

Startup on iOS (iPhone, iPad updated to the latest OS version) > 10 seconds
Android < 2 sec
Windows < 2 sec

Can't find any resources regarding this.

P.S. Xamarin Forms vanilla app built and deployed with Visual Studio 17.2 is much faster, < 4 sec on the same devices.

Comment: I've seen reports of this. However, those people have confirmed that this doesn't happen when they create a release build. Would you be able to verify that if you create a build, upload that to TestFlight if it still happens then? We still need to work on the deployment time while developing for sure, but at least then it won't be a blocking issue for production

Comment: Ok, I am perfectly fine if this doesn't happen with the release build. I can live with that during development.

I will try to make a testflight next week, so we will see.

Comment: For me, the startup is so slow that the splash screen times out every time debug or release. This is on an app that I have ported from Xamarin, which was much more performant.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis any GH issue that tracking it? An fixes being worked on? :)

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I did various kinds of builds and deployments.
The result:

1. Debug deployment from Visual Studio directly to iPhone. Startup > 10 seconds.
2. Debug deployment from Visual Studio to iPhone attached to paired Mac computer. Startup time = 3 seconds
3. Release build on Mac, deployed to TestFlight and then installed on iPhone. **Startup time = 1 second**.

So, the only slow thing is the direct deployment from Visual Studio to iPhone, but I can live with that.

Comment: Thanks for posting the results! I’m developing a Net MAUI Blazer Hybrid app and was noticing slow times on local dev deployment to iPhone (iOS). Good to know performance is much better in release build!